# Valgrind error "depends on uninitialized value", even though I'm sure the variable is being initialized

Tags: c, valgrind

I know this question is asked a lot, but I've looked up a ton of questions and none of them has the same problem I have. Valgrind is returning "Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation". I have the following type:

```c
typedef struct {
    char *str;
    short cond;
} analysis;
```

Because it's so simple and I don't want to manage memory, I'm allocating it in the stack. I did try allocating it on the heap, but I was still getting the same error with "heap" instead of "stack". The function `proc_line()` initializes a new instance of the type and returns it:

```c
analysis proc_line(char *s)
{
    /*
     *
     */

    analysis a = {
        .str = corrupt ? &corrupt : missing,
        .cond = corrupt ? CORRUPTED : MISSING
    };
    
    return a;
}
```

`corrupt` is a `char` and `missing` is a `char*`, that's why I reference it. It's used in this block:

```c
while ((s = str_input())) {
    analysis a = proc_line(s);

    if (a.cond == CORRUPTED)
        score += ret_score(*a.str, CORRUPTED);
    else {
        push_miss_score(&m, calc_miss_score(a.str));
        free(a.str);
    }

    free(s);
}
```

`ret_score()` is supposed to take a `char`, so I dereference the pointer to `char` from the struct. I'm getting an error only for the dereferenced pointer, not for the function that takes a pointer itself. Valgrind is saying that `analysis a = proc_line(s);` is uninitialized, but I'm clearly assigning the struct returned by `proc_line()` to `a`, and I'm also assigning all fields of `a` with a value in the function. I also tried writing it as `*(a.str)`, but of course nothing changed. As I said, even when allocating on heap and returning a pointer Valgrind still complains about the uninitialized value. How can this be?

Minimal reproducible example:

```c
// Advent of Code 2021 - Day 10

#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

//#include "strmanip.h"

#include <string.h>
#include <ctype.h>

char *str_check(char *s)
{
    if (!s) {
        s = calloc(1, 1);
        *s = '\0';
    }
    return s;
}

char *str_insert(char *s1, char* s2, unsigned long p)
{
    s1 = str_check(s1);
    s2 = str_check(s2);

    unsigned long len1 = strlen(s1);
    unsigned long len2 = strlen(s2);
    char *s_final = calloc(len1 + len2 + 1, sizeof(char));

    unsigned long i = 0;
    unsigned long j = 0;
    unsigned long k = 0;

    p = len1 ? p % (len1 + 1) : 0;

    while (i < p)
        s_final[i++] = s1[j++];

    while (k < len2)
        s_final[i++] = s2[k++];

    while (j < len1)
        s_final[i++] = s1[j++];

    free(s1);
    free(s2);

    s_final[i] = '\0';
    return s_final;
}

char *str_append(char *s1, char *s2)
{
    s1 = str_check(s1);
    return str_insert(s1, s2, strlen(s1));
}

char *str_push(char *s1, char c)
{
    char* s2 = calloc(2, sizeof(char));

    s2[0] = c;
    s2[1] = '\0';

    return str_append(s1, s2);
}

char str_pop(char *s)
{
    s = str_check(s);

    unsigned long len = strlen(s);
    unsigned long i = len ? len - 1 : 0;
    char c = s[i];

    s[i] = '\0';
    return c;
}

char *str_input(void)
{
    char buffer[1024] = { 0 };
    char *s = NULL;
    unsigned long cap = 0;
    unsigned int i = 0;
    char c = '\0';

    while ((c = getchar()) != '\n' && c != EOF) {
        buffer[i++] = c;
        buffer[i] = '\0';

        if (i == 1024) {
            s = realloc(s, sizeof(char) * (cap += 1024));

            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < i; ++j)
                s[cap - i + j] = buffer[j];

            memset(buffer, '\0', 1024);
            i = 0;
        }
    }

    if (i) {
        s = realloc(s, (cap += ++i));
        for (unsigned int j = 0; j < i - 1; ++j)
            s[cap - i + j] = buffer[j];
    }

    if (s) s[i - 1] = '\0';
    return s;
}

// Types
typedef struct {
    char *str;
    short cond;
} analysis;

typedef struct {
    long *list;
    int count;
    int cap;
} missing;

enum state {
    CORRUPTED,
    MISSING
};

// Function declarations
analysis proc_line(char *s);
_Bool is_opening(char c);
int ret_score(char c, enum state s);
long calc_miss_score(char *s);
void push_miss_score(missing *m, long n);
int compare_scores(const void *a, const void *b);

int main(void)
{
    missing m = {
        .list = NULL,
        .count = 0,
        .cap = 0
    };
    char *s = NULL;
    long score = 0;

    while ((s = str_input())) {
        analysis a = proc_line(s);

        if (a.cond == CORRUPTED)
            score += ret_score(*a.str, CORRUPTED);
        else {
            push_miss_score(&m, calc_miss_score(a.str));
            free(a.str);
        }

        free(s);
    }

    qsort(m.list, m.count, sizeof(long), compare_scores);

    printf("Part 1: %lu\n", score);
    printf("Part 2: %lu\n", m.list[m.count / 2]);

    free(m.list);

    return 0;
}

analysis proc_line(char *s)
{
    char *missing = NULL;
    char corrupt = '\0';
    unsigned long len = strlen(s);

    for (unsigned int i = 0; i < len; ++i) {
        char c = s[i];

        if (is_opening(c)) {
            c += c == '(' ? 1 : 2; // Turns into the closing character
            missing = str_push(missing, c);
        } else if (c != str_pop(missing)) {
            corrupt = c;
            break;
        }
    }

    if (corrupt)
        free(missing);
    else
        missing = str_push(missing, '\0');

    analysis a = {
        .str = corrupt ? &corrupt : missing,
        .cond = corrupt ? CORRUPTED : MISSING
    };

    return a;
}
        
_Bool is_opening(char c)
{
    return (c == '(' || c == '[' || c == '{' || c == '<');
}

int ret_score(char c, enum state s)
{
    switch (c) {
    case ')':
        return s == MISSING ? 1 : 3;
    case ']':
        return s == MISSING ? 2 : 57;
    case '}':
        return s == MISSING ? 3 : 1197;
    case '>':
        return s == MISSING ? 4 : 25137;
    }

    return 0;
}

long calc_miss_score(char *s)
{
    long score = 0;

    for (unsigned long i = strlen(s); i; --i) {
        score *= 5;
        score += ret_score(s[i - 1], MISSING);
    }

    return score;
}

void push_miss_score(missing *m, long n)
{
    if (m->count == m->cap)
        m->list = realloc(m->list, sizeof(long) * (m->cap += 256));

    m->list[m->count++] = n;
}

int compare_scores(const void *a, const void *b)
{
    int arg1 = *(const long*) a;
    int arg2 = *(const long*) b;

    if (arg1 < arg2) return -1;
    if (arg1 > arg2) return 1;
    return 0;
}
```

Input:

```
[({(<(())[]>[[{[]{<()<>>
[(()[<>])]({[<{<<[]>>(
{([(<{}[<>[]}>{[]{[(<()>
(((({<>}<{<{<>}{[]{[]{}
[[<[([]))<([[{}[[()]]]
[{[{({}]{}}([{[{{{}}([]
{<[[]]>}<{[{[{[]{()[[[]
[<(<(<(<{}))><([]([]()
<{([([[(<>()){}]>(<<{{
<{([{{}}[<[[[<>{}]]]>[]]
```

Full Valgrind output:

```
==40449== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==40449== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==40449== Using Valgrind-3.17.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==40449== Command: ./a.out
==40449==
==40449== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==40449==    at 0x109E95: ret_score (10.c:111)
==40449==    by 0x109C33: main (10.c:54)
==40449==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==40449==    at 0x109C0D: main (10.c:51)
==40449==
==40449== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==40449==    at 0x109E9A: ret_score (10.c:111)
==40449==    by 0x109C33: main (10.c:54)
==40449==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==40449==    at 0x109C0D: main (10.c:51)
==40449==
==40449== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==40449==    at 0x109E9F: ret_score (10.c:111)
==40449==    by 0x109C33: main (10.c:54)
==40449==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==40449==    at 0x109C0D: main (10.c:51)
==40449==
==40449== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==40449==    at 0x109EA4: ret_score (10.c:111)
==40449==    by 0x109C33: main (10.c:54)
==40449==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==40449==    at 0x109C0D: main (10.c:51)
==40449==
==40449== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==40449==    at 0x109EA9: ret_score (10.c:111)
==40449==    by 0x109C33: main (10.c:54)
==40449==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==40449==    at 0x109C0D: main (10.c:51)
==40449==
==40449== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==40449==    at 0x109EAE: ret_score (10.c:111)
==40449==    by 0x109C33: main (10.c:54)
==40449==  Uninitialised value was created by a stack allocation
==40449==    at 0x109C0D: main (10.c:51)
==40449==
Part 1: 26397
Part 2: 288957
==40449==
==40449== HEAP SUMMARY:
==40449==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==40449==   total heap usage: 267 allocs, 267 frees, 8,425 bytes allocated
==40449==
==40449== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==40449==
==40449== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==40449== ERROR SUMMARY: 20 errors from 6 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

Comment: Please show a [mcve]

Comment: Just a guess, but have you made sure *corrupt* is initialized? You didn't show any of that code.

Comment: I read the page and added a pastebin to what I think should be minimal reproducible examples.

Comment: @matticebox a [mcve] is not simply a link to an external source but it should be in the question and it should have been made as small as possible by removing all unrelated parts, but only so much that it still compiles and still reproduces the issue. That's of course some work for you. But in the process you might find the problem yourself.

Comment: @Jabberwocky I'm sorry, but it is as minimal as it can be. There's no point in removing the single and last function that's not involved with the analysis struct for the sake of crashing the entire program and not producing an output. I'll include the source and the input in the post itself.

Comment: @matticebox reducing the input might be helpful

Comment: @matticebox ... and you should update the valgrind report so it corresponds to your [mcve].

Comment: `return a;` Where will `a.str` point to? Local variable `corrupt` is no longer valid after returning from the function. That is a severe bug and needs fixing. But I don't see how this might cause the message about depending on uninitialized variable

Comment: @Gerhardh That's the solution. I know we're not supposed the thank in the comments, but you didn't post an answer, so I thought I should tell you that I'm grateful

Comment: As I mentioned, I don't see the a direct match with that issue and the valgrind message. Therefore I supposed something else must be fishy, too, and my hint was only a bonus finding. ;)

Comment: @Gerhardh Nope, that was exactly it. No more errors. I don't know how Valgrind works, but the errors were related to the bug.

Comment: Just a general tip... you have a type called `missing` as well as a local variable (in `proc_line`) called `missing`, I thought this would cause a compile-time error, but even if it doesn't it's confusing and bad practice.